# Update table in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling with the following (apparently) easy task; my table (call it table1) look like this:

```
id | date | value
------------------
 1 |   01 |   100
 1 |   02 |   103
 1 |   04 |   105
 1 |   05 |    90
 1 |   06 |    95
 1 |   09 |     0
 2 |   02 |   110
 2 |   03 |    98
 2 |   04 |    97
 2 |   07 |    71
 2 |   08 |    84
 2 |   10 |     0
------------------
```

I would like to replace the two 0s with, respectively 95 and 84 (i.e. previous values in time). Any solution? I have been spending a looot of time on this (sorry but I am quite new to SQL)

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. And you will need 2 update statements. 1 for each value you want updated.

Comment: just do two queries, one where the ID=1 and Date=09 after you update that one write a second query where ID=2 and Date=10 it doesn't have to be complex

Comment: Do you want to **update** the records in your table or do you want to write a **query** where the zeros are replaced by the previous values in the results?

Comment: @WEI_DBA   
  
this is what I have tried: UPDATE table1 SET value = CASE WHEN value=0 THEN 'previous value in time' ELSE value END

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   
I want to update the table

Comment: @SaggingRufus my table is more complicated than this, so I need something more general

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update table1 as a 
set a.value=(select b.value 
             from table1 as b 
             where b.date<=a.date order by b.date desc limit 1) 
where a.value=0;
```

Change to this

Make a new replica of table1 as table2 (same structure & same data in table1 and table2):

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update table1  
set value=(select value 
    from table2 
    where table2.date<table1.date order by table2.date desc limit 1) 
where table1.value=0;
```

Comment: If this actually runs without error it might be a valid approach.

Comment: already used something similar and it didn't work. EDIT: tried also this and it does not work

Comment: @v_emme: Please never ever say "it didn't work" here without telling us what exactly happened. Did you get an error message? Were incorrect values written?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Another join would probably fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on nacho's query:

MySQL's update is a bit flawed. First: it doesn't accept an alias for the updated table. Second: It complains when you access the same table you want to update in the query. The latter can easily be solved by replacing `from table1 b` with `from (select * from table1) b`.

nacho's statement also missed to have the subquery refer to the same ID. And he mistakenly included the record itself (`b.date <=` instead of `b.date <`).

```
update table1 
set value = 
(
  select b.value 
  from (select * from table1) b 
  where b.id = table1.id and b.date < table1.date 
  order by b.date desc limit 1
)
where value = 0;
```

And here is a test: http://rextester.com/YQV55035

**UPDATE: You obviously tagged the wrong DBMS. Here is the same query for SQL Server:**

```
update table1 
set value = 
(
  select top(1) b.value 
  from table1 b 
  where b.id = table1.id and b.date < table1.date 
  order by b.date desc
)
where value = 0;
```

Comment: this does not work, it gives: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

Comment: This is because you tagged your question with **MySQL**, but it seems now that your database system is actually **SQL Server**, which is another product and their SQL dialects differ. I have updated my answer.